# Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown

Tags: typescript, rust, blockchain, solana

I've encountered an error from the title on sending the transaction to Solana program (written in Rust). I'm trying to wrap my head around it, however I can't seem to make it work. What I've already established is:

- This is a deserialization issue (as it happens when I try to send the transaction).
- The error message claims that it cannot deserialize accounts, I think it means the "keys" from `web3.Connection.sendTransaction(programId, keys, data)` function signature.
- This "Unknown" is odd in my opinion. I've tried looking up the BorshIoError and it turned out that the error string is parametrized. This "Unknown" is the value of a parameter, which leads me to conclusion that either something is seriously wrong with my understanding or this is a silly coding mistake, but probably the first one, as I quite recently started to learn about Solana.

I made sure that the expected number of accounts matches what is expected in Solana program, however since it is a deserialization issue, I am quite convinced that it does not reach the program entry function.

The Instruction looks like this:

```js
const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
    programId: programId,
    keys: [
        { pubkey: publicKey1, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
        { pubkey: publicKey1, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
        { pubkey: publicKey2, isSigner: true, isWritable: false },
        { pubkey: publicKey2, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
        { pubkey: tokenAccount1, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
        { pubkey: programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
        { pubkey: tokenMintAccountPublickey, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
        { pubkey: programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
        { pubkey: programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    ],
    data: Buffer.from(Uint8Array.of(0, ...new BN(1000).toArray("le", 8))),
});
```

**I am aware that there are a lot of duplicate keys in that array.** I intend to fix that once the issue with deserialization is resolved, however I am quite convinced that it is not an issue with the keys themselves, as I also tried to generete 9 brand new keypairs (via `new Keypair()`) and requesting an Airdrop for the one which signs the transaction - this will 100% encounter an error defined in the program, but I still receive the same deserialization error. Of course only the public keys of the generated keypairs were used in the `keys`.

Then, the transaction is created and sent (at least attempted to) like so:

```js
const tx = new Transaction().add(instruction);
await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [signerKeyPair]); // signerKeyPair.publicKey == publicKey2
```

I am using localhost as a testnet for Solana. The Solana program is deployed.

It may be important, so here is the `instruction.rs` file:

```rust
#![allow(clippy::too_many_arguments)]

use {
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSchema, BorshSerialize},
};

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, BorshSchema)]
pub enum ProgramInstruction {
    ///   0. `[w]` account1.
    ///   1. `[]` account2
    ///   2. `[s]` account3
    ///   3. `[w]` account4.
    ///   4. `[]` account5
    ///   5. `[]` account6
    ///   6. `[]` account7
    ///   7. `[]` account8
    ///   8. `[]` account9
    Instruction(u64),
}
```

The program itself does define various errors, however none is encountered (and they would be if the transaction was processed by program, since that is one of the things I want to achieve).

My code was inspired by:

- Solana-labs helloworld example: https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld
- This tutorial: https://paulx.dev/blog/2021/01/14/programming-on-solana-an-introduction/

[EDIT]
This is the full error I am getting:

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown 
    Program programID invoke [1]
    Program log: Error: BorshIoError
    Program programID consumed 3271 of 200000 compute units
    Program programID failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
(node:4208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/home/user/Workspace/Solana/scripts/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6591:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/home/user/Workspace/Solana/scripts/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6550:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/home/user/Workspace/Solana/scripts/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6540:12)
    at async sendLegitimateTransactionToProgram (/home/user/Workspace/Solana/scripts/build/legitimateInteraction.js:88:5)
(node:4208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4208) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The `programID` from the above error has been obfuscated (as I am not sure if I can share it as I think it would be the same regardless if it was a testnet, devnet or mainnet). It is actually the legitimate programID (base58 encoded publikey of the program if I understand that correctly) and it is the one used in the Typescript as `programId`.

I think the first 5 lines of this errors are important. The rest is associated with Node and the fact that it was an async function which failed without any `.catch()`.

Comment: Please add more details about the error. Maybe a screenshot to can help.

Comment: @Mr.Arjun, Added the full error I am getting as requested.

Comment: it happen once to me when I used wrong value for account size when creating it. So this value was smaller than the actual expected size by program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what you're thinking, all of the accounts are properly getting sent in, but your program is failing to deserialize the data inside the account as whatever type you're expecting.

This is entirely a shot in the dark, but perhaps your account hasn't been created: https://docs.solana.com/validator/runtime#systemprogram-interface

Be sure that the right amount of data is already allocated / assigned to your program before running your instruction.